# Greyscale to black-opacity conversion

Tags: css, colors, hex, rgb, opacity

I have discovered

```
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
```

and

```
color: #333333;
```

and

```
color: black; opacity: 0.8;
```

all produce equivalent shades of grey.

How can I generalize this?

In other words, given an arbitrary RGB or HEX color/shade of grey, how can I determine the equivalent value of `opacity` when `color: black;`?

[Here is the Codepen Demo.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJqpoG?editors=1100)

```
<style>
  div {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 60px;
  }
  .rgb {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51); /* given this value... */
  }
  .hex {
    color: #333333; /* ...or given this value */
  }
  .opacity {
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.8; /* how can I determine this value? */
  }
<style>

<body>
  <div class="rgb">rgb(51, 51, 51)</div>
  <div class="hex">hex #333333</div>
  <div class="opacity">opacity 0.8</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.viget.com/articles/equating-color-and-transparency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this [Hextool](https://www.hexcolortool.com/) site too. Use the `RGBA`. Fourth value is the opacity of that color.

**Eg:-**

```
rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.87)
```

*87% Opacity*

Hex Opacity Values

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

Comment: Unsure how this solves the question asked. OP wants to convert any grayscale color into a black-based color with a different value for alpha.

Answer (score 8):

After facing a similar problem, I've built a tool to achieve that in your browser.
You just have to input your hex color, and it will give you a rgba equivalent.
Feel free to test it out ;)

https://aclarembeau.github.io/grayscale-to-opacity/